# Grails forwarding and/or redirection with parameters

Tags: grails, redirect, forwarding

Is it possible to do page forwarding in Grails? I searched but no luck. If possible, how do I pass parameters in the forwarding method? If not, how would I do it using redirection? I've found something like this for redirection so far:

Comment: You're using JSP, which is possible in Grails, but doesn't do anything "Grails"-y.  Ken's answer is how to do it in the Grails idiom.

Comment: Grails confuses redirects and forwards. It doesn't follow Java or Spring guidelines. As such, a redirect does BOTH. This is very confusing and most Grails developers won't know the difference between a redirect and forward as a result. Even PHP frameworks enforce forward vs redirect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Redirection is idiomatically done in a `controller` in Grails.  See the 
[`redirect`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#redirectsAndChaining) method in the [Grails User Guide](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest)

An example using parameters:

```
redirect(action:"show",id:4, params:[author:"Stephen King"])
```

You might also be able to accomplish a `forward` equivalent through the [URL Mapping](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings)  mechanism, including adding one or more parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken for the answer. :)

Comment: In addition to [`redirect`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) also see [`forward`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) and [`chain`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html).

Comment: This is technically a FORWARD even though the method is named 'redirect'; the functionality is of a forward. Grails confuses 'forwards' and 'redirects' and doesn't follow Java/Spring specs or guidelines.